# How to take data in one cell and move it to multiple cells in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm using excel 2013 and i have multiple words in cell A 
example:

```
  |    A     |    B     |    C     | 

1 "hello" ,
2 "world" , 
3 "Excel" ,
```

How can i get the words from cell A to cell B, C, D, E, F....etc

example

```
  |    A     |    B      |    C      | 

1  "hello" ,    "world" ,  "Excel" ,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transpose your matrix by copy / special paste transpose matrix.